# Convert the date format MM/DD/YYYY to DD-Mmm-YYYY using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

There is a text file showing date `(MM/DD/YYYY)` in column **4**. I would like to change the date format of column4 to `DD-Mmm-YYYY`.
when I use date `-d 08/31/2017 "+%d-%b-%Y"` command it works perfectly and convert the date format to `31-Aug-2017`. But when i am executing the same command using awk in bash script then its not working for me.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = FS;} {if(NR>1){$4=date -d $4 "+%d-%b-%Y";print} else{print}}' file >> tmpfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

test input file:

```
> cat input
aa,ss,dd,08/31/2017,sdf
```

---

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }NR>1{ split($4,a,"/"); 
     $4=strftime("%d-%b-%Y", mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",a[3],a[1],a[2]))) }1' input
```

The output:

```
aa,ss,dd,31-Aug-2017,sdf
```

---

About ***AWK Time functions***:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use | to redirect the date command and return the output and so if the 4th column is the one you are concerned about in the file "filename":

```
awk '{ print |"date -d "$4" \"+%d-%b-%Y\"" }' filename
```

The complete solution would be:

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=3;i++) { var=var$i"," } for (i=5;i<=NF-1;i++) { var1=var1$i"," } print |"echo "var"$(date -d "$4" \"+%d-%b-%Y\"),"var1$NF }' filename
```

We know that we are focusing on the 4th column so we build up a variable (var) with the columns 1 to 3 and then build a date command finally a building var 1 variable. All this then used to build an in directed echo command.

Comment: I believe, OP wants the whole line to be printed and not only the 4th column.

Comment: I was looking to give the user an idea of how to resolve the issue. I have added the complete solution none the less.